# rails - How to know if model is being saved by a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid, rake

Is it possible to know if a model is being saved/created/updated by a rake task? For example, I need to disable a before_save callback if the model is being saved by a rake task. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip **all** validations from the task you can [possibly use this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations).

If you want to conditionally run validations [you can use this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) in combination with setting some value on the model that would indicate that the validation should be skipped.

E.g., have a `validate` field on the model that stores whether or not that record should be validated.

```
validates :user_id, presence: true, unless: 'validate == false'
```

That's a bit of a hack.

If you're asking if there's some clean way for the code in the model to know where it's being called from...no, not that I know of. Use either conditional validations or one of the methods that are provided to skip validations for special cases.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about the second method as well: I will set the `validate` attribute only in my rake task models, then check for its existence in before_save and remove it afterwards, because it doesn't need to be persistent.

Comment: You can also use virtual attributes instead of creating a DB column. There's no reason you'll need to remove it afterwards if it never hits your database. When the model is saved to the DB it should only try persist attributes that map to DB columns.